# Android Arraylist find index

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of object in my `Fragment`.

```
ArrayList<MenuListItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuListItem>();
menuItems.add(new MenuListItem("Newsfeed", 20));
menuItems.add(new MenuListItem("FriendsRequest", 1));
menuItems.add(new MenuListItem("Messages", 2));

private class MenuListItem {
    public String label;
    public int count;

    public MenuListItem(String label, int count) {
        this.label = label;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

How can I find the index of object that has the label value "Messages" in my `ArrayList` from my `Activity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you try to iterate through elements of `menuItems`?

something of this sort:

```
for(MenuListItem menuListItem : menuItems){
    if (menuListItem.label.equals(<what you are looking for>){
        <do something>
        break; // in case when 1st occurence is sufficient
    }
}
```

side note (not related make your members private and add accessors for them)

Edit: just noticed that you are looking for an index, what i have included is to get an `MenuListItem` what you can do is iterate and return index if you want.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
        String search="Messages";
        for(int i=0;i<menuItems.size();i++){
            if(menuItems.get(i).label.equalsIgnoreCase(search)){
                System.out.println("Index " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int indexOf(final List<MenuListItem> menuItems, final String what) {
    final int size = menuItems.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        final String label = menuItems.get(i).label;
        if (label != null && label.equals(what)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a easier and standard way to do this.

**Eclipse**

Right-click inside `MenuListItem` class and select  `Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()` once you are done generating the implementations of these methods. You can use `ArrayList.indexOf(Object)` to get the index of the item you are looking for.

**IntelliJ** or **Android Studio**

Right-click inside your editor and click on `Generate` and from the dialog that pops up, select `hashCode() and equals()`.

The Collections framework has made things easier for you already. Why not leverage it instead of writing loops to find objects? :)

PS: This can be hand written, but this is something best left to the IDE. Because having too many attributes makes it tricky to get it right the first time.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio. I checked and it is not possible here.

Comment: No matter what, you could do that with Android Studio too. hashCode() and equals() are methods inherited from the Object class. You can do it manually, but it's a task best left to the IDE - Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ.

Comment: @Rani, this is how you do it with IntelliJ - http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generate-equals()-and-hashcode()-wizard.html

Comment: I have to find the index of the variable and not the object itself. That's why I had to loop.